# BT121 or BLE121LR - GATT.xml for custom services

Tags: bluetooth, gatt

The app on the tablet uses the Simple Profile with characteristics UID : FFF4 (the app is not written by me)

What do I need to write in the GATT.xml file to pass the data from the Bluetooth module to the tablet app (100-150 bytes of data) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Somebody? I really need your help!